Can not convert a generic struct type to a generic interface type in golang
Given there's a generic interface:
type Packet interface {
    Content() int
}

type Recycler[T any] interface {
    Get() *T
}


and their implementation:
type packet struct {
    content int
}

type BaseRecycler[T any] struct {
    t T
}


its impossible to convert the implementation to the interface:
    r := &BaseRecycler[packet]{}
    r1 := r.(Recycler[Packet]) 
        fmt.Println(r3.Get().Content()) // compile error: Unresolved reference 'Content'

here is a live code example: https://go.dev/play/p/qbnYfyDd22A
The error is because the Packet interface align with the *packet instead of packet. Could anyone suggest how to handle this?

You are assuming covariance in type parameters, which Go does not have - types must match exactly. You would need variance annotations like Kotlins in and out or Javas wildcards for that.
As the FAQ states:

In Go method types must match exactly, [...]. Programmers who want covariant result types are often trying to express a type hierarchy through interfaces. In Go it’s more natural to have a clean separation between interface and implementation.


To be a little more concrete, you could implement your packet like (Go Playground):
type packet struct {
    content int
}

func (p packet) Content() int {
    return p.content
}

and then an interface abstracting that:
type Packet interface {
    Content() int
}

Also the BaseRecycler:
type BaseRecycler[T any] struct {
    t T
}

func (b BaseRecycler[T]) Get() T {
    return b.t
}

and an abstraction thereof:
type Recycler[T any] interface {
    Get() T
}

Note some simplifications: The methods don't have pointer receivers (they serve no purpose in this example) and BaseRecycler does return a type, not an address.
Now you can simply use that:
    var r Recycler[Packet] = BaseRecycler[Packet]{t: packet{}}
    fmt.Println(r.Get().Content())

Also, you could define a PacketRecycler which has a concrete packet type and is not generic:
type PacketRecycler struct {
    t packet
}

func (p PacketRecycler) Get() Packet {
    return p.t
}

and use it in an identical fashion:
    var r1 Recycler[Packet] = PacketRecycler{}
    fmt.Println(r1.Get().Content())


You can fix the compile error by dereferencing the *Packet (pointer to the Packet interface) from r3.Get():
r := &BaseRecycler[packet]{}
var r1 interface{} = r
r3 := r1.(Recycler[Packet])
fmt.Println((*r3.Get()).Content())

You can call Content() on the resulting Packet (interface), by definition of interfaces.
Unfortunately, this is not a solution, because a runtime error occurs on the previous line. You cannot use type assertion to convert an interface{} containing *BaseRecycler[packet] to Recyler[Packet] as those are incompatible types (note the capitalization of packet). You can redeclare r, using Packet (interface), to make it work:
r := &BaseRecycler[Packet]{
    t: &packet{},
}
var r1 interface{} = r
r3 := r1.(Recycler[Packet])
fmt.Println((*r3.Get()).Content())

The trade-off is that this other part of your code example will no longer compile, for similar reasons:
r2 := r1.(Recycler[packet])
fmt.Println(r2.Get().Content())

Hopefully you don't need both type assertions for your use-case.
